# Javascript breaking text across multiple lines while maintaining indentation

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
const taskErrorMessage = (task, reason) => {
    const account = task.account;
    return {
        message: `ERROR. ACTION: ${task.action}. ACCOUNT: ${account._id}, \
${account.name}. REASON: ${reason}. DATE: \
${new Date()}`
    }
}
```

It doesn't fit on one line so I am breaking it up using `\` however it seems that if I try to add indentation the final string will be incorrect with unwanted spaces. Is there a way to break a string into multiple lines whilst maintaining indentation?

Comment: Does this have to be solved in javascript? Or can we use HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bare template literals, spaces at the start of lines are always interpreted literally, so they can't be used for code indentation.

If you want all whitespace collapsed, you could imitate this functionality with a [tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

```js
const $_ = (strings, ...vals) => {
    let result = ''

    strings.forEach((str, idx) => {
        result += str
        if (typeof vals[idx] !== 'undefined')
            result += vals[idx]
    })

    return result.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
}

console.log(
    $_`hooray
          indents for    every
                               ${1}
    `
)
```

However, note that this will run at run-time, not compile-time. It's unlikely to be a performance bottleneck unless you're creating hundreds of thousands of strings this way, but worth considering all the same.

Comment: I tried literal line breaks and it's breaking the line which I don't want

Comment: I've edited my answer with a possible solution, if you don't mind the performance overhead.